# jquery checkbox :checked is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have a view in MVC application which accesses model data like this,

```
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
        <tr>
            <td class="details-control" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NoOfProducts)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsEnabled.Value, new {id = "chkIsEnabled", onclick = "EnableDisableProduct(" + item.ProductId + ")"})
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)</td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn icon-btn btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new
                    {
                        ProductId = item.ProductId
                    })">
                <span class="glyphicon btn-glyphicon glyphicon-plus img-circle text-primary"></span>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

Below is my JavaScript function,

```
function EnableDisableProduct(ProductId) {
    if ($("#chkIsEnabled").is(':checked')) {
        alert("checked");
    } else {
        alert("unchecked");
    }
}
```

I have 5 checkboxes in my table so when I check/uncheck on the first checkbox, it works perfectly. But when I check/uncheck rest of the checkboxes, it keeps displaying checked or unchecked based on last click.

For example,

```
 1st checkbox checked   - "checked" alert box,
 2nd checkbox checked   - "checked" alert box,
 1st checkbox unchecked - "unchecked" alert box,
 3rd checkbox checked   - "unchecked" alert box,
 4th checkbox checked   - "unchecked" alert box
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes) and your `$("#chkIsEnabled")` selector will only ever select the first element with `id="chkIsEnabled"`

Change you checkboxes to use class names instead

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => item.IsEnabled.Value, new { @class = "chkIsEnabled" })

$(".chkIsEnabled").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert("checked");
    } else {
        alert("unchecked");
    }
}
```

Side note: You use of a `foreach` loop means that your checkboxes will not bind to you model when you submit the form. And you use of `IsEnabled.Value` suggests the property is a `nullable boolean` which means it still will no bind even if you use a `for` loop or `EditorTemplate`

Comment: I need to pass productId on checkbox click event

Comment: To get the value then its `var value = $(this).val()` but you have other major problems (read the last paragraph of my answer - your code can never work if you want to bind to your model)

Comment: And what do you mean _pass productId on checkbox click event_? No where in you existing code are you passing the productId

Comment: I also suggest you understand [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and stop using obsolete code.

Comment: I was passing it on checkbox click event, but it works now.

Comment: OMG. Read and understand my answer again, particularly the last paragraph. Everything your doing is wrong.

Comment: I understand  but I am not binding it's value with model on submitting the form. I am writing ajax call in checked and unchecked events to set enable disable values in sql table which works right now.

Comment: Then at least do it correctly and use unobtrusive javascript.

Comment: I will for sure try this with unobstrusive javascript. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This answer should have been chosen as the correct answer.

Comment: And if your not binding to your model, then don't use the HtmlHelpers (which are designed for binding to your model). You might as well just use `<input type="checkbox" class="chkIsEnabled" value="@item.ProductId " />` inside the loop and save yourself generating unnecessary html

Answer (score 1):

Element Id must be unique. So change your template to this:

```
<td>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsEnabled.Value, new {onclick = "EnableDisableProduct(this, " + item.ProductId + ")"})
</td>
```

This way you actually don't need it at all:

```
function EnableDisableProduct(checkbox, productId) {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        alert("checked");
    } else {
        alert("unchecked");
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to pass productId on checkbox click event

Comment: Sure, you can do it of course, check updated answer.

Comment: Using `onclick()`? Are you serious? It's 2015.

Comment: @ataravati Nothing wrong with onclick actually. Ah, unobtrusive JS, sure-sure :)